# R extract substring from end of pattern until first occurance of character

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Struggling for hours to get this match and replace in R `gsub` to work and still no success.
I'm trying to match the pattern `"Reason:"` in a string, and extact everything AFTER this pattern and until the first occurance of a dot (`.`)
For instance:

```
Offer Disposition. MSISDN: 7183067962. Offer: . Disposition: DECLINED. Reason: Not interested. ChannelID: CARE.
```

would return `"Not interested"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
s <- "Offer Disposition. MSISDN: 7183067962. Offer: . Disposition: DECLINED. Reason: Not interested. ChannelID: CARE."

sub(".*Reason: (.*?)\\..*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "Not interested"
```

---

*Update* (to address comments):

If you also have strings that do not match the pattern, I recommend using `regexpr` instead of `sub`:

```
s2 <- c("no match example",
        "Offer Disposition. MSISDN: 7183067962. Offer: . Disposition: DECLINED. Reason: Not interested. ChannelID: CARE.")

match <- regexpr("(?<=Reason: ).*?(?=\\.)", s2, perl = TRUE)
ifelse(match == -1, NA, regmatches(s2, match))
# [1] NA                                "Not interested. ChannelID: CARE"
```

For you second example, you can use the following regex:

```
s3 <- "Delete Payment Arrangement of type Proof of Payment for BAN : 907295267 on date 02/01/2014, from reason PAERR."

# a)
sub(".*type (.*?) for.*", "\\1", s3)
# [1] "Proof of Payment"

# b)
match <- regexpr("(?<=type ).*?(?= for)", s3, perl = TRUE)
ifelse(match == -1, NA, regmatches(s3, match))
# [1] "Proof of Payment"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. works. However, of condition of match is FALSE (does not find pattern "Reason:"), the whole string is being returned. Why and how to avoid this (Null should be returned) ? thanks

Comment: and also - how would your code change if the END character of the match is a word (in my case "For") instead of a dot (.) ? Such that from the sentence : "Delete Payment Arrangement of type Proof of Payment for BAN : 907295267 on date 02/01/2014,  from reason PAERR." the regex sub(".*type (.*?)\\..*", "\\1", s) will return the string between "type" and first occurance of "for" ( i.e. "Proof of Payment") ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lots of different ways (as you can see from the submissions). I personally like to use `stringr` functions.

```
library(stringr)

rec <- "Offer Disposition. MSISDN: 7183067962. Offer: . Disposition: DECLINED. Reason: Not interested. ChannelID: CARE."
str_match(rec, "Reason: ([a-zA-Z0-9\ ]+)\\.")[2]
## [1] "Not interested"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
x <- "Offer Disposition. MSISDN: 7183067962. Offer: . Disposition: DECLINED. Reason: Not interested. ChannelID: CARE."

library(qdap)
genXtract(x, "Reason:", ".")

##     Reason:  :  . 
## " Not interested"
```

Answer (score 0):

with regexepr and regmatches:

```
str <- "Offer Disposition. MSISDN: 7183067962. Offer: . Disposition: DECLINED. Reason: Not interested. ChannelID: CARE."
m<-regexpr("(?<=Reason: )[^.]+", str, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(str, m)
```